# I've two columns with Volume_daily and Volume_mean. I'm unable to compare the volume_daily data with volume mean in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, pandas-groupby

**I've two columns with Volume_daily and Volume_mean. I'm unable to compare the volume_daily data with volume mean in pandas.**

The code is below

```
merged[['Date', 'Company', 'Volume_daily', 'Volume_mean']]
```

The output is :

```
    Date             Company    Volume_daily    Volume_mean
0   03-MAY-2021      20MICRONS  192281  9.478021e+05
1   04-MAY-2021      20MICRONS  194547  9.478021e+05
2   05-MAY-2021      20MICRONS  61186   9.478021e+05
3   06-MAY-2021      20MICRONS  165283  9.478021e+05
4   07-MAY-2021      20MICRONS  110032  9.478021e+05
... ... ... ... ...
31046   02-JUN-2021  PROZONINTU 1841536 1.187079e+06
31047   02-JUN-2021  GOKUL  2410360 2.881602e+06
31048   03-JUN-2021  GOKUL  3352844 2.881602e+06
31049   03-JUN-2021  BHAGYAPROP 404151  4.041510e+05
31050   03-JUN-2021  PDMJEPAPER 2582062 2.582062e+06
```

**How to calculate percentage of Volume_daily and Volume_mean? For example volume_daily of 20MICRONS is 10 rs and is greater than volume_mean then the new column must show % increase, same for all other rows. If there is a decrease, then it must show decrease**

Comment: Can you add expected ouput from sample data in question?

Comment: Yes man, thankyou. write that code normally, i'll mention that answer is correct

Comment: Super, please edit question with this new column, then I think some solution(s) will be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is like this:

```
df['Volume_change_%'] = ((df['Volume_daily'] - df['Volume_mean']) / df['Volume_mean'] * 100).round(1).astype(str) + '%'
```

Result:

```
print(df)


              Date     Company  Volume_daily  Volume_mean Volume_change_%
0      03-MAY-2021   20MICRONS        192281     947802.1          -79.7%
1      04-MAY-2021   20MICRONS        194547     947802.1          -79.5%
2      05-MAY-2021   20MICRONS         61186     947802.1          -93.5%
3      06-MAY-2021   20MICRONS        165283     947802.1          -82.6%
4      07-MAY-2021   20MICRONS        110032     947802.1          -88.4%
31046  02-JUN-2021  PROZONINTU       1841536    1187079.0           55.1%
31047  02-JUN-2021       GOKUL       2410360    2881602.0          -16.4%
31048  03-JUN-2021       GOKUL       3352844    2881602.0           16.4%
31049  03-JUN-2021  BHAGYAPROP        404151     404151.0            0.0%
31050  03-JUN-2021  PDMJEPAPER       2582062    2582062.0            0.0%
```

If you want to show a positive sign `+` for increase, you can also use:

```
df['Volume_change_%'] = ((df['Volume_daily'] - df['Volume_mean']) / df['Volume_mean'] * 100).round(1).map(lambda x: ('+' if x > 0 else '') + str(x) + '%')
```

Result:

```
print(df)


              Date     Company  Volume_daily  Volume_mean Volume_change_%
0      03-MAY-2021   20MICRONS        192281     947802.1          -79.7%
1      04-MAY-2021   20MICRONS        194547     947802.1          -79.5%
2      05-MAY-2021   20MICRONS         61186     947802.1          -93.5%
3      06-MAY-2021   20MICRONS        165283     947802.1          -82.6%
4      07-MAY-2021   20MICRONS        110032     947802.1          -88.4%
31046  02-JUN-2021  PROZONINTU       1841536    1187079.0          +55.1%
31047  02-JUN-2021       GOKUL       2410360    2881602.0          -16.4%
31048  03-JUN-2021       GOKUL       3352844    2881602.0          +16.4%
31049  03-JUN-2021  BHAGYAPROP        404151     404151.0            0.0%
31050  03-JUN-2021  PDMJEPAPER       2582062    2582062.0            0.0%
```

Or simplify it using f-string, as follows:

```
df['Volume_change_%'] = ((df['Volume_daily'] - df['Volume_mean']) / df['Volume_mean']).map(lambda x: f'{x:+.1%}')
```

Result:

```
print(df)


              Date     Company  Volume_daily  Volume_mean Volume_change_%
0      03-MAY-2021   20MICRONS        192281     947802.1          -79.7%
1      04-MAY-2021   20MICRONS        194547     947802.1          -79.5%
2      05-MAY-2021   20MICRONS         61186     947802.1          -93.5%
3      06-MAY-2021   20MICRONS        165283     947802.1          -82.6%
4      07-MAY-2021   20MICRONS        110032     947802.1          -88.4%
31046  02-JUN-2021  PROZONINTU       1841536    1187079.0          +55.1%
31047  02-JUN-2021       GOKUL       2410360    2881602.0          -16.4%
31048  03-JUN-2021       GOKUL       3352844    2881602.0          +16.4%
31049  03-JUN-2021  BHAGYAPROP        404151     404151.0           +0.0%
31050  03-JUN-2021  PDMJEPAPER       2582062    2582062.0           +0.0%
```